# Cypher query that will return only 1 relation of each type between two nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I craft a query that will return only one relation of a certain type between two nodes?

For example:

```
MATCH (a)-[r:InteractsWith*..5]->(b) RETURN a,r,b
```

Because (a) may have interacted with (b) many times, the result will contain many relations between the two. However, the relations are not identical. They have different properties because they occurred at different points in time.

But what if you're only interested in the fact that they have interacted **at least once**?

Instead of the [result as it appears currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5oNk.png) I'd like to receive a result that has either:

- Only one random relation from the set of relations between (a) and (b)
- Only those relations that fit to some criteria (e.g. "newest" or one of each type, ...)

One approach I have thought of is creating new relations of the type "hasEverInteractedWith". But there should be another way, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shortestPath()` to get the quickest single result.

```
MATCH (a)-[:InteractsWith*..5]->(b)
WITH DISTINCT a, b
MATCH p = shortestPath((a)-[:InteractsWith*..5]->(b))
RETURN a, b, RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS r
```

If you want to get a specific one, you'll have to get all of the `r` and then filter them down, which will be slower (but provide more context).

```
MATCH (a)-[r:InteractsWith*..5]->(b)
WITH a, b, COLLECT(r) AS rs
RETURN a, b, REDUCE(s = HEAD(rs), r IN TAIL(rs)|CASE WHEN s.date > r.date THEN s ELSE r END)
```

Comment: The first query gives an error (Variable a not defined) and when I add "MATCH (a)-[r:InteractsWith*..5]->(b)" before the WITH it still says "Type mismatch: expected Path but was Collection<Path> (line 3, column 28 (offset: 124))
"RETURN a, b, RELATIONSHIPS(p) AS r""

Comment: I updated the answer. `shortestPath` is a pattern and not a function, so it behaves differently than expected sometimes. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you, there is no error now. But I still don't achieve the desired result with the first query. This is what I get: https://imgur.com/delete/MHVsZw1u3enfH4X

Comment: The visualizer is set to Auto-Complete by default, displaying all relationships between nodes it displays even if the query does not return those relationships. There is a toggle at the bottom-right of the view window to turn this off.

Comment: Ok, I knew that, should have known... Sorry for bothering you again and THANKS!